# how to load large reports asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, wcf, rest

how to load large data in form of bulk reports on asp.net web form, what is best option i can have, to make loading faster and printing pages without delay of more than 2 second, please any suggestions thanks.  I have already tried crystal reports but reports need a lot of custom formatting like headers and footers, so any other option . can i consider jqtable for this ?

Comment: How you want to load it via ajax ?

Comment: yes ajax is necessary to avoid large post backs, but performance is critical to load it quickly, and print as well.

Comment: And will you use paging ?

Comment: no paging is not an option here because we want to show long page with scroll.

Comment: But too much data will hang the browser if you load it using ajax.

Comment: do not consider ajax as part of solution